# Why is Mint asking me to update a closed account?

Tags: mint.com

A few months ago I closed one of my bank accounts. I’ve marked the bank as closed, but Mint is asking me to update my login credentials.

I've attempted to re-enter my credentials several times. However, since my bank account was closed, the login fails each time. I would like to tell Mint to ignore this error, but I haven't found any way of doing this.

**Why is Mint asking me to update login information for a closed account? Can I make Mint ignore errors for a closed account?**

[image: Mint closed account]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After talking with Mint's customer support, I was able to resolve the issue changing by my account status to active, then closing it again.

1. Go to the account **Settings** page.

   [image: Account Settings]
2. Locate the closed account and click **∧** to open a submenu
3. Mark the account Status as **Active**
4. Refresh the page and remark the account status as **Closed**